# Problem getting data from linked server error in SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I m working in SQL and I have few tables in Oracle database from which I have to get data, so I m doing so via linked server. If I omit date filter then the query works fine but if I apply date filter then it breaks.

This query works fine.

```
select * from openquery([ORCL], 'select sls_value, retailer_cd, tery_cd, inv_dt
from Toc_cust_second_sls_new where cust_cd IN ( ''1-ZUT42P'' )') secSls --- This query works fine
```

This query breaks

```
select * from openquery([ORCL], 'select sls_value, retailer_cd, tery_cd, inv_dt from Toc_cust_second_sls_new where cust_cd IN ( ''1-ZUT42P'' )
and to_date(inv_dt, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') between to_date(''01/05/2020'', ''dd/mm/yyyy'') and to_date(''31/05/2020'', ''dd/mm/yyyy'')') secSls
```

I get this error.

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORCL" returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".

To filter date I can use this query as it works fine.

```
select * from openquery([ORCL], 'select sls_value, retailer_cd, tery_cd, inv_dt, inv_no, cust_cd from Toc_cust_second_sls_new 
where cust_cd IN ( ''1-ZUT42P'' )') secSls
where convert(date,secSls.inv_dt, 101) >= '2020-05-01' and convert(date,secSls.inv_dt, 101) <= '2020-05-31'
```

But the problem in the above query is, it first gets all the data from oracle then it filters so there are hundreds if thousands of records which takes a lot of time.

Comment: What is the datatype of inv_dt? It sounds like it is already a DATE datatype .

Comment: `lakhs` isn't an English word. Both Oracle and SQL Server have date types so no conversion to or from date should be necessary. In fact, that's what probably causes the error. If `inv_dt` is a date, trying to convert it to date *again* as if it were a string may actually *convert* it to a string using the server's locale, just to convert it back to a data. If `inv_dt` contains a string instead of a date, a) you have a VERY serious bug and b) most likely that string doesn't match the US date format

Comment: BTW using the US date format for literals or stored values just begs for trouble. For one thing, it can't be sorted alphabetically so it can't take advantage of indexing. Use the ISO8601 format at least (yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I removed the conversion of inv_dt in oracle as it's data type was already Date, trying to again convert it was creating problem.

```
select * from openquery([ORCL], 'select sls_value, retailer_cd, tery_cd, inv_dt from Toc_cust_second_sls_new where cust_cd IN ( ''1-ZUT42P'' ) and inv_dt between to_date(''01/05/2020'', ''dd/mm/yyyy'') and to_date(''31/05/2020'',''dd/mm/yyyy'')') secSls
```

This query works now. Thanks guys who helped me out on comments section.